# I have a while loop and inside it I want to convert PHP to Valid json

Tags: php, encode, json

My while loop is:
I have tried to insert `json_decode` and `json_encode` and also each one of them without the other, but have had no luck. I keep getting the error ***JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data***

```
while ($row = $res->fetchRow()){
    $resGold = $row['gold'];
    $resSilver = $row['silver'];
    $resBronze = $row['bronze'];
    $resGdp = $row['gdp'];
    $resPopulation = $row['population'];
    $resCountry = $row['country_name'];
    $gold_score = ($resGold * $gold_value);
    $silver_score = ($resSilver * $silver_value);
    $bronze_score = ($resBronze * $bronze_value);
    $score_pop = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resPopulation);
    $score_gdp = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resGdp);
    if($population == 'true'){ 
        $result = $res->fetchRow();
        $result['score'] = "$score_pop";
        json_encode($result);
    }
    else if($gdp == 'true'){ 
        $result = $res->fetchRow(); 
        $result['score'] = "$score_gdp"; 
        json_encode($result);
    }
}
if($population == 'false' && $gdp == 'false'){
    echo "Please select either population or gdp from view.htm";
}
```

I understand that the `json_encode` has to be out of the while loop but don't understand how to do this.
Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: what are you attempting to **encode** you've not provided such information.

Comment: @CurtisCrewe I want to encode the `$result` as shown in the code above. I get the white-space error when the `json_encode` is in the while loop, but when I put it outside, I only get 1 (the last) result back instead of all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular error you have cited (*JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data*) is when Javascript is decoding it.

`json_encode` returns a string from the mixed value argument. [json_encode Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

You would either need to `echo` out the result or add it to another variable to output later.
eg.

```
while ($row = $res->fetchRow()){
    $resGold = $row['gold'];
    $resSilver = $row['silver'];
    $resBronze = $row['bronze'];
    $resGdp = $row['gdp'];
    $resPopulation = $row['population'];
    $resCountry = $row['country_name'];
    $gold_score = ($resGold * $gold_value);
    $silver_score = ($resSilver * $silver_value);
    $bronze_score = ($resBronze * $bronze_value);
    $score_pop = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resPopulation);
    $score_gdp = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resGdp);
    if($population == 'true'){ 
        $result = $res->fetchRow();
        $result['score'] = "$score_pop";
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    else if($gdp == 'true'){ 
        $result = $res->fetchRow(); 
        $result['score'] = "$score_gdp"; 
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
if($population == 'false' && $gdp == 'false'){
    echo "Please select either population or gdp from view.htm";
}
```

If you are trying to encode multiple rows and return them all, you would be better off adding the `$result` to an array and encoding that outside the `while` loop as if you don't, your JSON string could look like:

```
{gold:123,silver:456,bronze:789}{gold:987,silver:654,bronze:321}
```

That is not valid JSON as it can only parse one object or array at once. Below is a valid JSON string

```
[{gold:123,silver:456,bronze:789},{gold:987,silver:654,bronze:321}]
```

That is an array representation of your data and will parse into a list of your JSON encoded objects. Here is your code using an array to store the JSON before echoing it.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = $res->fetchRow()){
    $resGold = $row['gold'];
    $resSilver = $row['silver'];
    $resBronze = $row['bronze'];
    $resGdp = $row['gdp'];
    $resPopulation = $row['population'];
    $resCountry = $row['country_name'];
    $gold_score = ($resGold * $gold_value);
    $silver_score = ($resSilver * $silver_value);
    $bronze_score = ($resBronze * $bronze_value);
    $score_pop = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resPopulation);
    $score_gdp = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resGdp);
    if($population == 'true'){ 
        $result = $res->fetchRow();
        $result['score'] = "$score_pop";
        array_push($results,$result);
    }
    else if($gdp == 'true'){ 
        $result = $res->fetchRow(); 
        $result['score'] = "$score_gdp"; 
        array_push($results,$result);
    }
}
if($population == 'false' && $gdp == 'false'){
    echo "Please select either population or gdp from view.htm";
}
else
{
    //Note: This is in the 'else' statement as echoing the JSON then that string
    //      will also cause errors as it ends up not being valid JSON anymore
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

As in my example above you are echoing the string regarding selecting population or GDP, as that isn't JSON encoded and the part above would otherwise be encoded in JSON, you may have parse errors when trying to decode it. If this PHP page is meant to return JSON encoded data and your error message isn't JSON encoded, it is likely to have problems with whatever is getting the value.